# SAX data collection design pattern

Tags: java, database, collections, sax

I am new to Java development, and looking for general design patterns for a data collection application written in Java.
I have already written the prototype, which is a basic Java console application that uses SAX to retrieve data and store it in a database.

Obviously, this is not a Web app, so it doesn't need to run in a container like Tomcat, but what would people recommend?  The application currently uses a basic Java timer to run every 5 minutes.

So the basic requirements that I can think of are

1. It needs to run all the time, so if it crashes, it needs to be restarted.
2. It needs to do its work every 5 minutes, so it needs a timer.
3. It *could* use Hibernate, but not if it creates any overhead, as this is a highly
   date intensive application.

So what I am looking for are suggestions like:

You could run a timer widget thingumbob under Tomcat anyway and get requirement #1.... or Spring 99 has all of the features you need.

etc.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of application you could have a main process that spawns a thread that does the actual work.  This thread would be in a loop that basically checks to see if it supposed to be running or not.  If it is running it continues.  Once it does its work you can use Thread.sleep(msToSleep) to put the thread to sleep for 5 minutes. So it would go in a continuous cycle of working and sleeping.  Not timer required. The main process can "ping" the thread to see if it is still functional and if it is not spawn a new thread.  Depending on the OS there are similar techniques to make sure the main process is running.  Using an ORM like Hibernate will add overhead so you will have to way the trade-offs between transaction performance and ease of development.  If you are converting your data to objects yourself you will have to use a profiler to see if you are actually implementing it more efficiently than an ORM can.

Comment: Kevin,  

Thanks for the reply.

I know how to create a thread and monitor it from the main process. I was wondering if there was some other, well-established pattern using one of Java's many frameworks.

Comment: Just taking a stab at an answer with the limited information provided.  If you provide a little more context on the problem you will probably get more answers.  Frameworks are not required for the simple polling described here.  What do you want from the framework?  What is the datasource?  An XML file?  Why are you using SAX? What is the data store?  Is this an extract-transform-load (ETL) process?